# DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 Output

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, displayport, adapter

I just bought myself an Asus Swift PG278Q gaming monitor. When I bought it I was led to believe it had both DisplayPort and HDMI, to which I later found out its limited to the DisplayPort. I have an Alienware 17 R3 laptop with an HDMI 2.0 output. Is it possible to connect my laptop to the monitor with a DP to HDMI adapter? Will it support 2560 × 1440? If not I'll just take back the monitor if possible. If that's the case what kind of monitor should I get? If I could use both my laptop and my Xbox one with the same monitor that'd be a plus.

Comment: Your dell laptop probably has displayport support via the USB-C port (with adapter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change the monitor, it can be done but only with an active adapter (that is, hdmi output to a display port input)

Looking around, these adapters seem to be quite expensive (>$100 USD), and being active conversation I wouldn't guarantee you'd get all your monitors functionality.

Note that you can't use a cheaper DP output to HDMI input adapter, as DP to HDMI can be done passively, but not vice versa.

Edit: as stated above, your machine does have display port support up to 4k through the USB port, so that would be another option if you want to keep the monitor.

More info on DP over USB C - http://www.displayport.org/what-is-displayport-over-usb-c/

And example cable - https://store.google.com/product/usb_type_c_to_displayport_cable

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'd like to learn more about the display port support through USB. Is that a viable option? Would I need that >$100 adapter if I went with that? Or simply a DP to USB cable?

Comment: @MikeyMarc added to my answer

Comment: Great! But with that cable my refresh rate would be limited to 60hz from the 144hz I'd be getting from Display Port, right? Also could you link me to an example of the adapter I'd need if I were to use my Xbox one with this monitor? I've done a little research myself but I see nothing but cheaply made adapters under $20. I'm sure that's not what I need.

Comment: @MikeyMarc you should get the full rate supported, 4K@60hz is the maximum, but lower resolutions would support higher refresh rate. The Xbox would require a more expensive active adapter though, like this one. http://www.startech.com/m/AV/Converters/Video/Active-HDMI-or-DVI-to-DisplayPort-Converter~HDMI2DP - personally, I'd consider another monitor with HDMI, probably less of a headache all around.

Comment: Oh I see...Sadly I've decided to return the monitor. But at least I've learned a lot about them in the process! I'm currently looking for something else. Do you know if there are g-sync monitors with HDMI connections?  Or is HDMI typically for freesync instead?  Are g-sync monitors compatible with Xbox One without an adapter? I've been looking at freesync monitors and I've found this one: Asus MG279Q. I don't know much about freesync but I'm sure it's second best to g-sync. I'm not a pro gamer or anything so g-sync isn't something I absolutely need.

Comment: However, I do enjoy the cleanest picture possible whilst gaming, like any other enthusiast. Will freesync suit my fancy? I've noticed the difference in Pixel Response between the Asus Swift PG278Q and the Asus MG279Q; 1ms vs. 6.5ms. How much of a difference does that 5.5ms make? Also, if you have any other monitor suggestions that are compatible with both my Alienware 17 R3 and my Xbox One please let me know! I appreciate the time you've put into this on my behalf. You'da best +++ Rep

Comment: I've answered several of my questions above with this link: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2402169,00.asp                          Are any of these monitors worth getting?